# How IDA pro creates assembly code from binaries?

Tags: assembly, binaryfiles, ida

## How to create assembly from compiled binary?

*i am learning x86 assembly programming. so i came to know about gdb,objdump and IDA pro , these are the programs that creates **assembly from binaries**.i wonder How do they create assembly from binaries? when i open binaries in notepad it shows a lot of symbols ,numbers and letters. my doubt is that how do they create assembly from compiled binaries?*

Comment: Opening non-text files with Notepad isn't useful.  It's all just bytes, but some happen to be in the ASCII range and some aren't.  It's just a coincidence that some of the bytes show as numbers and letters.

Comment: What IDA does is failry complicated which is why the program is so expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly has (roughly) a 1:1 correspondence to machine code<sup>1</sup>, so in line of principle there's nothing too complicated about disassembling: once you have a block of machine code and the address where it has to be loaded, you start with the first instruction and start decoding.

On RISC architectures this work is generally easier, since machine instructions have generally a fixed size, usually very regular - "classic" ARM and PowerPC, for example, use fixed-size 32 bit instructions, where part of the bits specify the assembly instruction, the parameters, etc. On x86 the situation is a bit more complicated, both because it is a variable-length instruction set, and because it evolved irregularly over time.

Generally an assembled instruction is made of one or more bytes of *prefix* (which may translate back to assembly prefixes such as `rep` or `lock`, specify that the instruction is operating on data on a different segment or of a different size than the default, or select a different sub-instruction set altogether - see e.g. the VEX prefix), one opcode (a byte that specifies the instruction plus possibly part of the parameters), followed by the parameters (there's a somewhat regular encoding to specify immediates, registers or memory operands, with their various addressing modes). See [this nice diagram](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0020_encoding_overview.htm) (and in general that site) for a more detailed explanation of the general x86 instruction format.

Once it has decoded the instruction, the disassembler has to resolve relative addresses/jumps (applying them to the current position in the code) and emit the corresponding assembly, possibly making up label names for jump targets (or just leaving the jump targets as plain addresses).

Now, this is just the low-level part, which is what a "raw" disassembler (such as `ndisasm`) can do. But, apart from particular cases (such as COM files in MS-DOS), executable files are not just the raw code to be executed by the CPU, but are more structured binary formats.

Generally an executable contains several sections, which can contain different kind of data. Usually there's a section for the assembled code (often named `.text`), plus several sections for program data (mutable and immutable, zero initialized, incorporated resources, ...) plus other accessory information for the loader, such as the dependencies from dynamic linking libraries and relocation information. A more sophisticated executable inspection tool (such as objdump, nm or dumpbin) can parse executable formats, decode their structures and - if requested - disassemble the code it finds in the code sections.

On the top of this, tools such as IDA add quite some intelligence - they parse the executable format, partially perform the job of the loader (applying relocations to the code), disassemble the code and perform a lot of analysis on it - it tries to follow the code flow, propagates type information if available (typically starting from OS APIs, whose entry points are well known), examines access patterns to global data to infer its type, ...

---

1. That is, minus comments and "high level" features, such as macros, label names and jumps where you leave the best way to calculate the target address to the assembler. Also, the distinction between instructions that are synonyms (e.g. `je`/`jz`) is obviously lost - a disassembler will typically just emit one of the possible synonyms when decoding opcodes.

Answer (score 2):

A more concise answer is that IDA Pro is a "recursive descent" tool.  This means that, after identifying the binary header and sections, it begins disassembling code from the start of the text segment (more specifically, at the entry point).  Following that, it will begin to follow branches, recursively descending through the code, attempting to identify and follow those branches rather than simply assuming that the code is all aligned sequentially from the beginning of the text segment.

This works very, very well, and is not as easily confused as something that disassembles linearly, but it still cannot follow branches through jump tables and other dynamically calculated branches.